# Wordle letter-flipping animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/ercancem/pen/JjZjEJL?editors=0110)

I am trying to replicate the letter flipping animation in [Wordle](https://www.nytimes.com/games/wordle/index.html). But I cannot manage the smooth chaining/sequencing. How can I fix it? (I guess I need to use the JS Promise feature, but yet to understand that concept.)

```js
function myFunction() {
    var tiles = document.getElementsByClassName("inner");
    var myArray = Array.from(tiles);
    myArray.map(function (tile) {
        tile.classList.add("flip-in");
        // tile.style.setProperty("--flipColor", "green");
        tile.addEventListener(
            "animationend",
            () => {
                tile.classList.remove("flip-in");
                tile.style.backgroundColor = "green";
                tile.classList.add("flip-out");
            },
            {
                once: true
            }
        );
        return;
    });
}
var flipper = document.getElementById("flipper");
flipper.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

Answer (score 2):

You've essentially done it but probably overengineered it a bit. The wordle animation is pretty simple to accomplish using only one animation.

First, let's take care of the CSS animation. Since we will only use one animation for the entire flip we can rename it "flip".

To simulate the card "flipping" we can adjust the scale on the height rather than flipping it. At the same time, we can also apply the background color change.

We can also remove the animation-delay styles. We will apply these dynamically in the JS.

```
@keyframes flip {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }

  50% {
    background: white;
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
    background: green;
  }
}
```

We have to mark the animation as `fill-mode: forwards`

```
.flip {
  animation: flip 500ms ease forwards;
}
```

Next, we can simplify the JS to only apply the class. Do some renaming to easier understand what everyone is and does. And here we can also dynamically apply the animation delay based on the index of the tile. This way we will support all different number of tiles.

```
function applyFlip() {
  var tiles = document.getElementsByClassName("inner");
  var tilesArray = Array.from(tiles);
  tilesArray.map(function (tile, i) {
    tile.classList.add("flip");
    tile.style.animationDelay = `${i * 100}ms`;
  });
}
var flipper = document.getElementById("flipper");
flipper.addEventListener("click", applyFlip);
```

Here's a working snippet:

```js
    function applyFlip() {
      var tiles = document.getElementsByClassName("inner");
      var tilesArray = Array.from(tiles);
      tilesArray.map(function (tile, i) {
        tile.classList.add("flip");
        tile.style.animationDelay = `${i * 100}ms`;
      });
    }
    var flipper = document.getElementById("flipper");
    flipper.addEventListener("click", applyFlip);
```

```css
.container {
  width: 540px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 2px;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

button {
  margin: 50px;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 4px;
}

.flip {
  animation: flip 500ms ease forwards;
}

@keyframes flip {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }

  50% {
    background: white;
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
    background: green;
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner">S</div>
    <div class="inner">T</div>
    <div class="inner">A</div>
    <div class="inner">C</div>
    <div class="inner">K</div>
  </div>

  <button id="flipper"> Flipper </button>
```